# Why is input="date" changing values between browser and server?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I have a `<input type="date">` field on my webpage and cannot understand why the value of this input changes when I send it via a HTTP POST request from the browser (using AngularJS) to the server (Java). Here is an example of what happens:

```
Date selected in browser via <input type="date">:       Wed Jan 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)
Date that appears on server when sent via POST request: 2018-01-23T13:00:00.000Z
```

It appears that, on the server-side, the value changes from the browser's timezone to UTC (in this case from Australia/Sydney to UTC).

How can I use `<input type="date">` to just send the date portion of the value without having the timezones converted and dates messed up?

Comment: That sounds like desirable behavior.  I mean, consider you have a browser in AUS, one in the US, and one in India.  Do you really want them all reporting their local time?  How would you figure out what time they really meant?  "Everything is UTC" sounds like a better idea to me.

Comment: I understand that logic, however what I am trying to achieve is just save the date portion regardless of timezones. If the user selects `2018-01-24` I want this to show up in the server as `2018-01-24` with no alterations.

Comment: Then you'll have to go through the same steps that you normally would to display a local date-time to a user.  Get the locale from the browser, convert UTC to local date-time, extract the year, month and day.

Comment: A date library like [momentJS](https://momentjs.com) may be of intrest to you

Comment: And if it's on the server and Java, probably `java.time`.

Comment: @markspace—you can't reliably "*get the locale from the browser*".

Comment: With your corrected data excerpts, this is obviously a simple time zone adjustment. Midnight in Australia is eleven hours ahead of UTC, so it is also 1 PM previous date in UTC/GMT, very same moment. This has been covered many many times before on Stack Overflow. Please search before posting.

Comment: As I have stated before, I understand this is a time zone adjustment and have searched around. My questions is different as I am looking for a way to pass dates, please read my question before posting.

Comment: Search ["ISO 8601"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) & ["java.time"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), discussed many many times on Stack Overflow, as is advice about working in UTC being generally best. Also, nothing was "messed up", you ended up with the same moment, the same point on the timeline.

Comment: If a user selects 24 Jan 2018 in the date input, the input will have a value of "2018-01-24". If parsed on the client using the built-in parser, it will be interpreted as UTC so for Sydney/Australia will be "2018-01-23T13:00:00Z". If you don't want that, you should pass the value as text and not have it parsed locally.

Answer (score 0):

## Failure

The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

So `2018-01-24T00:00:00.000Z` and `2018-01-23T13:00:00.000Z` do *not* represent the same moment. They represent two different moments in history, two different points on the timeline, eleven hours apart.

If you are certain that pair of values were intended to be the same moment, then something went wrong. This is *not* an adjustment in time zone.

We cannot further diagnose the source of the error as we lack information.

Comment: @RobG Isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: I have updated the times in my example, that was just a copy-paste error. The times are intended to be the same moment, but more importantly, the dates remaining the same between browser and server is what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

What probably happens is your server converts it to it's local timezone.
Why it happens? To normalize your time.
Imagine situation where someone from UK sends date (for example `12am 2018.01.22`), and then someone from US receives it, and it will show him exact same time, even if it's different time zone (different time for him).
What you want to do is to calculate timezones(webpage side), or if it's not something you want to achieve, try changing your servers time zone.

Comment: This is *not* a change of time zone, not in the normal correct sense. The `Z` means both are in UTC. So these values represent two different points on the timeline. Something went wrong. See my Answer.

Comment: I was writing my answer when you posted yours @BasilBourque. And yes, you are right about it. I didn't pay attention to `Z` at the end

Comment: I think you're right. On 2018-01-24 Sydney is +1100, so UTC would be 13:00 the previous day.